# Allow adding accented URL to the "Website link" field in the user's profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I'd like to add a link in my profile with a domain name which contains an accent, but when I save the changes, the accent is removed resulting in a different URL.

For example, from **accentu*é*s.com**, it goes to **accentus.com**.

Could we have accents in the "Website link" field?